# How to create GUI in dotnet core in Linux?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, .net-core, monodevelop, gtk#

Need for laboratory programming. I have monodevelop and there safely run Gtk# c mono, but I would like to run Gtk# with dotnet core. There are still vscode with dotnet core, but I don't know how to connect it to Gtk#.
Is it possible to change monodevelop to mono for dotnet core?
OR
Is it possible to do so would be in vscode worked with Gtk#?

Comment: I don't think so unless there's some project that's provided core bindings for it in the very recent past. Could be wrong.

Comment: http://avaloniaui.net might be an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit of a late reaction. Recently started using [Avalonia UI](http://avaloniaui.net/), which supports a lot of  the standard WPF XAML. Also using Avalon Studio, which can be built on your Linux, if you'd like to develop on Linux, for Windows you can use a Avalonia addon for Visual Studio. Avalon Studio mimicking a very basic Visual Studio (like 2005/2008 express/community editions), but it is very unstable.